# Rename all files found by extension in for loop

Tags: file, unix, grep, rename, ls

My task is to write a script that searches for all files without `.old` extension within given directory and renames files to this format: `filename.old`. I've tried this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(grep "\.[^old]&" $1 | ls)
do
 mv "$1/$i" "$1/$i.old"
done
```

but it gives a wrong output.

- These files were in my directory: `f1, f2.old, f3, f4.old`.
- Expected output: `f1.old, f2.old, f3.old, f4.old`.
- My output (1st launch): `f1.old, f2.old.old, f3.old, f4.old.old`.
  Each time when I launch script it keeps adding `.old` extension, so it becomes like this:
- My output (2nd launch): `f1.old.old, f2.old.old.old, f3.old.old, f4.old.old.old`.

How can this be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a one-liner like so:

```
find . -mindepth 1 ! -name '*.old' -exec mv {} {}.old \;
```

Example on GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):

```
mkdir so
cd so
touch f1 f2.old f3 f4.old
find . -mindepth 1 ! -name '*.old' -exec mv {} {}.old \;
ls
```

Result:

```
f1.old f2.old f3.old f4.old
```

Explanation:

- `find .` means find in current directory
- `-mindepth 1` will return the files without returning the current directory `.` (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/153770/how-to-have-find-not-return-the-current-directory)
- `! -name '*.old'` will skip any files ending with `.old`
- `-exec mv` executes the `mv` (move) command on the returned files denoted with `{}` and adds an extension to it with `{}.old` meaning whatever-filename-was-returned.old

You can modify your script like so to get similar result:

**test.sh.old**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(find . -mindepth 1 ! -name '*.old'); do
        mv "$i" "$i.old"
done
```

Execute with `bash test.sh.old` to get similar results.

You may have to try some test cases to see if the one-liner and the modified `test.sh.old` file passes those test conditions. I tested it with the sample you provided and this returns the desired results.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution work perfectly.  I used yours script with one change, replaced . with $1.